# TFS doesn't add all projects

Tags: tfs

I added my solution to TFS source control and half of the projects are missing!

The solution references the guids in the project files (not that I changed them).

I noticed they weren't added because the changes don't show up in the pending changes. I checked and those projects don't show up in source control explorer.

I don't understand: if VS can recognize what projects a solution has, why can't TFS ?

Comment: Did you see any error message in the Output window of Visual Studio when you tried to add the solution to TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a workaround, but I ended up doing it manually:

```
tf add myfile.cs
```

Not a strongpoint for TFS if this not user error.